# Adding the ZeroMQ PHP extension to XAMPP on Windows 10 and PHP7

Tags: php, windows, apache, xampp, zeromq

I am having issues adding the ZeroMQ PHP extension to XAMPP.

Setup: Windows 10, PHP7, XAMPP (7.0.9)

**Steps I already took:**

1. Added PHP (`D:\xampp7\php`) and PHP extensions (`D:\xampp7\php\ext`) directories to system variable (PATH)
2. Followed the instructions on [zeromq.org](http://zeromq.org/bindings%3Aphp#toc4). I downloaded [x86ts](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/zmq/1.1.3/php_zmq-1.1.3-7.0-ts-vc14-x86.zip) version from the [pecl repository](http://pecl.php.net/package/zmq/1.1.3/windows) as the listed snapshot link (http://snapshot.zero.mq/) was down.
3. Copied `libzmq.dll` into PHP directory and `php_zmq.dll` into the PHP extension directory
4. Updated `php.ini` (`D:\xampp7\php\php.ini`) by adding `extension=php_zmq.dll` and checked the extensions directory which is `extension_dir="D:\xampp7\php\ext"`
5. Restarted XAMPP via the control panel.

The Apache error log shows the following:

```
[Sat Nov 26 18:30:27.461679 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 15280:tid 588] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Nov 26 18:30:27.546320 2016] [core:warn] [pid 15280:tid 588] AH00098: pid file D:/xampp7/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Sat Nov 26 18:30:27.630955 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 15280:tid 588] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'D:\\xampp7\\php\\ext\\php_zmq.dll' - Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
[Sat Nov 26 18:30:27.662208 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 15280:tid 588] AH00455: Apache/2.4.23 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2h PHP/7.0.9 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Nov 26 18:30:27.662208 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 15280:tid 588] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Jul  1 2016 11:09:37
[Sat Nov 26 18:30:27.662208 2016] [core:notice] [pid 15280:tid 588] AH00094: Command line: 'd:\\xampp7\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d D:/xampp7/apache'
[Sat Nov 26 18:30:27.662208 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 15280:tid 588] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 964
[Sat Nov 26 18:30:28.363210 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 964:tid 616] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
```

---

**Update:**

It looks like the module cannot be found, but if I add the x64 Version the Apache error log indicates that the module is not a not a valid Win32 application.

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'D:\\xampp7\\php\\ext\\php_zmq.dll' - %1 ist keine zul\xef\xbf\xbdssige Win32-Anwendung.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
```

---

**Solution:**

Adding `LoadFile "D:/xampp7/php/libzmq.dll"`to httpd.conf fixed my issue.

Comment: please write answer on the answer section.. but i'm glad you sorted it out.

Answer (score 9):

these steps worked for me (php 7.1.7 - xampp - window 10 x64)

**Step 1**

download x86 dll files from [this site](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/zmq/1.1.3/)

**Step 2**

copy `php_zmq.dll` to `C:\xampp\php\ext`

**Step 3**

copy `libsodium.dll` and `libzmq.dll` to `C:\xampp\php`

**Step 4**

add `extension=php_zmq.dll` to `php.ini` file

**Step 5**

restart apache

Comment: Yeah I though so too, but I experience that you have to also add the `Loadfile ...` statement for the `libzmq.dll`

Comment: I get crash in apache with Loadfile

Comment: Wrong path probably?

Comment: If it works for you it should not matter, but if the file and path was correct it should not make any problems. See the `LoadFile` Directive of Apache http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_so.html#loadfile

Comment: @mostafaznv How to install in xampp on Mac?

Comment: @tisuchi I didn't test it on mac

Comment: This Steps are same in all tutorials. I have windows 10, x64 arch, xamp with php 7.2 and follow this steps except Step 3, i only copy `libzmq.dll` to `C:\xampp\php` and i  added `C:\xampp\php\ext` to System Enviroment Variables. Try with differents `php_zmq.dll` files until `php -m` shows zmq module without warnings. 
Persevere and you will get it

Comment: @ju_ +7 votes for this answer. it seems it's right answer for your question. please hit that button :D

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question although I just spent 2 days trying to get ZeroMQ to load properly. If anyone still cant get it to work after following all the basic instructions, I have 2 more steps you can look into.

Got it working with php 7.3.12, Win10 x64

1st. **Make sure you edit all php.ini files.**

If you use wamp server, Apache will have it's own php.ini that is opened up when you click on the wamp icon in the bottom right of windows and go to php->php.ini. Then manually add the same `extension=php_zmq.dll` there as well as your php.ini under `D:\xampp7\php\php.ini`. To be honest, I'm not 100% sure that this is necessary but including it on both cant hurt.

2nd. **Run deplister.exe on libzmq.dll**

This is what got it working for me. Any php download from windows.php.net should have deplister.exe (it is included in wamp php versions too). Go to your php version library on your wamp server where `libzmq.dll` and `deplister.exe` are located. Then open up cmd and run the line: `deplister php_zmq.dll` This will show you a list of the dependencies that `php_zmq.dll` requires to run. You may notice that it requires a VERY specific version of `libzmq.dll` so go and rename your dll file to the requested file name. Then run `php -m` to see if `zmq` is displayed on the list of modules. If so, you should be able to run commands like `composer update` to get the required library versions imported into your project without error!

Comment: This seems to only work with php7, i have 8 installed and I really don't work to reinstall anything..Do you have any suggestions?